# Check for missed calls

Tags: android, android-intent

I have found this code to check if I have any missed call:

```
String[] selection = { CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
            CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL, CallLog.Calls.TYPE };
String where = CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "=" + CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE
                + " AND " + CallLog.Calls.NEW + "=1";
Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI,
                selection, where, null, null);
c.moveToFirst();
if (c.getCount() >= 0) {
    mIntent.putExtra(MainActivity.PARAM_STATUS, MainActivity.STATUS_MISSCALL);
    sendBroadcast(mIntent);
}
```

I need to know where to put this code, because I need it to be executed continuosly... The idea is to execute this and if there are any missed call, the code sends a message to the `MainActivity`. Maybe a new activity?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer by myself.

I have used a Thread with a sleep of 1000 milliseconds this way:

```
final Handler mhandler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    mhandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
  }
};

Thread missedCall = new Thread() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (true) {
        int a = missCall();
        if (a > 0) {
          runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              mArrayAdapter.add("Missed Call...");
            }
          });
        }
        sleep(1000);
        mhandler.post(r);
      } 
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
};
missedCall.start();
```

And I define `missCall` like this:

```
public int missCall() {
        String[] selection = { CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
                CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NUMBER_LABEL,
                CallLog.Calls.TYPE };
        String where = CallLog.Calls.TYPE + "="
                + CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE + " AND "
                + CallLog.Calls.NEW + "=1";
        Cursor c = this.getContentResolver().query(
                CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, selection, where,
                null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        return c.getCount();
    }
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do this, but it works for me.